# Start the MainActivity from another module in the current project

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I am trying to start an activity from another module in the same project. I use Retrofit Client and at `onResponse` I want to start the main activity from another module. I imported the module in my project with "Import new module from Android Studio Bar"

I tried to use Intent with `Class.forName()` but it doesn't work, I also tried to add in the manifest the activities. I have the project Lab that contains two modules: app(com.example.lab) and home(he.kome.lis) modules. When I tried to add in app-manifest the activity from home it is red and I get `"Unresolved class"`.

This is how my manifest for app looks like:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.lab.LogInActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="he.kome.lis.AddActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: Did you properly added modules as dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I did, I can run each module independently in the same project, but cannot call the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, you need to make the imported module as a library module by changing its module `build.gradle` plugin from:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

to:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

**Second**, if you need to hide the implementation details of how to call the Activity modules you can use a Navigator [singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java) inside your library module:

```
public class Navigator {
    private Navigator(){}

    public static Navigator getInstance() {
        return NavigatorHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class NavigatorHolder {
      private static final Navigator INSTANCE = new Navigator();
    }

    public void navigateToMainActivity(Context context) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, LibrariesMainActivity.class);
      context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then you can launch the MainActivity of library module with:

```
Navigator.getInstance().navigateToMainActivity(this);
```

Comment: it is added as a library, still does not see MainActivity.class from library, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not properly added them as your dependency 
Go to project and right click and then select open module settings go to dependencies tab and click '+' button on right side (beside scope label) and click modules option and select required dependency click OK